# How to wrap quotes in thunderbird automatically

Tags: email, plaintext, thunderbird

When replying emails with long lines, I have to break the quotes manually which is very annoying, because I have to use the context menu for pasting as quote (e.g.: no Ctrl-V).

I did searches from time to time, because the cases I need this feature are very rare. But so far I have found nothing helpful. Maybe I'm suffering of a very special blindness?

---

Edit: I forgot to make clear, that I'm replying via plain text email.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the trick, and it's **so simple**!

Use **Edit -> Rewrap** (or **Ctrl-R**) in the composition window.

Why did it take me so long to find it? I simply could not imagine that the composition window has its own menu...

...and I guess I'm not the only one, who has problems understanding Thunderbird's way of wrapping quotes, see the NEW(!) [196033 – Automatically wrap quotes in replies/followups (optional?)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196033) and its duplicates...

Comment: Wow, thank you! I ask myself why I have never asked this question aunt google.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrap, all formatting and images are lost. What is needed is a method of getting html text to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Edit → Preferences ⇢ Advanced ⇢ Config Editor* and search for *wrap.* Set all booleans to *true* and `mailnews.wraplength` to 0. This way all lines will be wrapped according to the window width dynamically and no actual linebreaks will be inserted that may possibly disturb the rendering for your recipient (as it [should be](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/37745/43730)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a look on it. Maybe it has changed since I asked the question (as I observe sometimes for some open source software). BTW there is no menu path like Edit -> Preferences ->Advanced in my Thunderbird (German version, but also no obviously translated version of it)

Comment: @Wolf: *Advanced* is a tab in the *Preferences* dialogue, not a submenu.

Comment: Well, but then your `Edit →` is misleading. I see the advantage of your suggestion, but I'm not sure how good this works in my environment.

Comment: On the other hand, reading my question today, I find your approach pretty illuminating.